# install sinhala unicode pack

Tags: unicode

Ubuntu has the built in sinhala unicode support. But it is not the 'wijesekara' keyboard layout. ( http://www.ucsc.cmb.ac.lk/ltrl/services/layout/ ) . How ever 'wijesekara' type pack is available in the web site ( http://www.siyabas.lk/sinhala_how_to_install.html ) . But the problem is it is only available for ubuntu 9.04. I tried to install this package in ubuntu 11.10. But failed :-(. What should I do?

Comment: Having same problem setting up Sinhala, Tamil, English keyboard for friend. I'll be watching this thread.

Comment: The method on this page almost seems to work http://sinhala.sourceforge.net/

Comment: yes... it installs sinhala... but not the usual keyboard layout!!

Comment: iBus is the solution - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ibus

Answer (score 2):

I also have this problem. Sinhala-lk-lug font can be installed using the following command (as root):

By installing using the above command and making suitable setting in Language Support {ibus} and Keyboard Input Methods {add required languages} Sinhala unicode could be used without any trouble in 12.04 as well as previous versions of Ubuntu. But for some time now, although the language selector shows up there it is not possible to type using Sinhala. This might be caused due to a regular software update.

Note: When using the above-mentioned long command to install Sinhala Unicode, the Terminal gives a message that instead of "ttf", "fonts" will be selected.

http://mtechzone.blogspot.com/2011/11/unicode-sinhala-fix-in-linux-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://www.siyabas.lk/sinhala_how_to_install.html#lin) will provide the source for the solution. The original Debian 6 source has been revised for compatibility with Ubuntu.

• Open the terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-sinhala-lkmug ibus im-switch ibus-m17n m17n-db m17n-contrib language-pack-si-base
rm -f ~/.xinput.d/* ; im-switch -z all_ALL -s ibus
```

• Logout and login again. Environment variables need to be set/updated (NO NEED TO REBOOT).

• Select your keyboard layouts by opening the terminal and running:

```
ibus-setup
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and wanted to make Wijesekara layout work somehow. So I have created my own XKB mapping file. If you need you can use it.

All the information is in this GitHub repository. https://github.com/para-d/si-wijesekara-keyboard

Answer (score 0):

**For the old Ubuntu editions**

1. Open terminal & type

`sudo apt-get install ttf-sinhala-lklug ibus im-switch ibus-m17n m17n-db m17n-contrib`

2. Download whatever the sinhala font you like (.ttf files).
3. Copy those `.ttf` files on `/usr/share/fonts/sinhala/` folder.
4. Type `ibus-setup` on terminal and go to the input method tab.

[image]

a. Select Add

b. Select Sinhala-Sinhalese and OK

c. Click En in Top right corner of your screen.

[image]

d. Change it to Sinhala.

**for Ubuntu 14.04 or heigher**

1. Open terminal and

`sudo apt-get install ibus-m17n m17n-db m17n-contrib`

2. Do 2 and 3 steps in above mentioned if you want more sinhala fonts.
3. Go to `settings` and select `Region & Language`

[image]

4. Add sinhala unicodes in `Input Sources`.
5. Top of the right corner there is `en` mark. From that select sinhala font that you add.

[image]

ඇන්ඩ් එන්ජෝයි ටයිපින් sinhala.

**for Ubuntu 20.04**

Package `m17n-contrib` is not available

so that

`apt install ibus-m17n m17n-db`

and follow from the 3rd step.
if sinhala fonts not apply, please logout and login again.